# PSQL - ERROR: expected a right parenthesis

Tags: windows, psql

Using Windows 10 and PSQL I can not seem to edit functions. When I type:

```
\ef [functionname];
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  expected a right parenthesis
```

It should call up notepad to edit the function.... please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave off the trailing `;`.